# Store string values in a variable using sh

Tags: bash, sh

I need to store this tags values in a variable in a .sh file.

```
TAGS = "sample=test" \
        "appenv=dev"
```

But it's throwing parsing error while printing using `echo $TAGS`.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To assign a variable in Bash or `sh`, you need to use `VARNAME=val` with no spaces around the `=`.

If you type something like

```
IFS='|' read -r a b
```

the shell will interpret that as

1. Use the value `|` for the variable `IFS`—**but only for the command on this line**.  (The value of `IFS` variable for subsequent commands will be whatever is already stored there.)
2. Execute the command `read` passing it the arguments `-r`, `a`, and `b`.

The shell also uses quotation marks (`"`) and equal signs (`=`) for its own purposes. If you need those in the variable, you can use single quotes so the shell treats everything inside them as regular characters.

```
$ TAGS='"sample=test"
> "appenv=dev"'
```

Now my `TAGS` variable has the value `"sample=test"\n"appenv=dev"`. That `\n` is the newline character I typed after `…test"`. Because I had an open single quote `'`, Bash knew I wasn't done with the command, so it put the `\n` in the value and prompted me with `>`  to continue.